# Entity framework Model to multiple database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have one project，need build more then 300 models, i want use EF codefirst.

But I think saved in one database Seems not so good.

so I want to know how to Save more then 300models to 5 database and use code first?

Do it right?

How to do it?

Have the mature example ?

how to query data by Navigate properties in tow models? They are not in same database，

I want query by lambda int these database like One database (on DbContext).

I am chinase .so  English is very Bad.

I hope you can understand what I'm saying

Comment: In order to get an answer you will need to give more details.  What is your problem exactly? be more specific.

Comment: @codea Seems like he believes that 300 tables in one database is too much and wants to split it into 2 or more database but in his application kinda merge those databases into 1 model so he is basically asking if this is possible or what's the best practice is when working with a "high" number of tables. Split Database, split the model, or keep everything as it is. The answers tend to be opinion based so I guess the question will be closed as too broad.

Comment: how to Save more then 300models to 5 database and use code first?

Comment: how to query data by  Navigate properties in tow models?

Comment: They are not in same database

Comment: Please, make your question shorter. It includes too many questions

Answer (score 0):

The problem with splitting the models across multiple databases is that you cannot have foreign key relationships between the two databases.

If you are using multiple databases you will need to handle all the navigation yourself in code.

You should consider redesigning the database so that there are less base models and then using application level models to access the required models.

Another option is to use ubermodels keeping all 300 tables and then use application level models. This can be aided by techniques proposed in the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx) on shrinking EF models that may help.

Comment: This is only my idea.I even don't know its right.I have one、

Comment: project，need build more then 300 models, i want use  EF codefirst.But I think saved in one database Seems not so good. so I want to know how to Save more then 300models to 5 database and use code first?

Comment: how to query data by Navigate properties in tow models? 
They are not in same database